# Custom Report in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, metrics, dimensions, universal-analytics

I am new to Google Analytics.I want to create custom report which should look like this [image: custom report]What will be my custom metrics and custom dimensions and what changes i need to do in my tracking code to generate such kind of report.

Answer (score 1):

I second faridghar answer. However, to get a straight response to your question I will suggest creating a custom report and using other tools to accomplish what you want to achieve. Simply follow this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y_OiIyLC4cI) steps. It will explain everything except the email ID issue, you can still follow their instructions to implement a similar solution as they did with the user's names.

Answer (score 0):

It is forbidden to collect personally identifiable information (PII) in Google Analytics. In your example, "Client Name", "Email ID" and "Address" are all PII. Therefore, while it may be technically possible to achieve this, you would be violating Google Analytics policy. More info [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6366371?hl=en#features).

One way around this would be to hash the data before you send it to GA. This would only really make sense for the email field as your other fields are probably not unique.